# Number of ways of forming a committee of 6 members from 10 teachers and 4 students

Tags: combinatorics

From 10 teachers and 4 students, a committee of 6 members is to be formed, with at least 2 students in the committee.
My first approach is to add the number of combinations of exactly 2 students, exactly 3 students and exactly 4 students and obtained the correct result.
My second approach is C(4, 2) *C(12, 4)... The logic being, the number of ways of choosing two students out of four multiplied by number of ways of choosing 4 persons out of remaining 12 persons, that way there will be at least 2 students in the committee of 6. And I get the wrong result with this approach. I don't know the mistake in my logic in the second approach. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your incorrect second method, cases with more than 2 students are being overcounted.

For example a group with 3 students A, B, C and 3 teachers can be formed by first choosing A&B, and then the other 4 people which happens to include student C. It can also be formed by first choosing A&C, and then 4 more people which happens to include student B. And also by first choosing B&C.

So cases with 3 students are counted 3 times with this method. Cases with 4 students are counted even more times. Therefore this method gives an answer that is too high.